# Bad version number in .class file. on embedded oc4j in Jdev 10.1.3.4.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdeveloper, oc4j

I'm converting a project from running in Netbeans on tomcat to running in jdeveloper on the embedded tomcat. But I've run into this error:

```
oracle.classloader.util.AnnotatedClassFormatError: Bad version number in .class file
```

I have read that it'd be something about version, but I've compiled all internal jars to 1.5 and made sure that my project also targets 1.5

Any suggestions for how to resolve, or how to "upgrade" the embedded OC4j

Full stacktrace:

```
2014-05-21 07:39:32,014 [HTTPThreadGroup-4] ERROR org.apache.commons.digester.Digester - Begin event threw exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(PropertyUtils.java:1789)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.setNestedProperty(PropertyUtils.java:1684)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.setProperty(PropertyUtils.java:1713)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:1019)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:808)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin(SetPropertiesRule.java:259)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:200)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1273)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseElement(NonValidatingParser.java:1288)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.ValidatingParser.parseRootElement(ValidatingParser.java:146)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:303)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:206)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1548)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile(ActionServlet.java:1006)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:955)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:470)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:256)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.loadServlet(HttpApplication.java:2379)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.findServlet(HttpApplication.java:4830)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.findServlet(HttpApplication.java:4754)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.initPreloadServlets(HttpApplication.java:4942)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.initDynamic(HttpApplication.java:1144)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.<init>(HttpApplication.java:741)
    at com.evermind.server.ApplicationStateRunning.getHttpApplication(ApplicationStateRunning.java:431)
    at com.evermind.server.Application.getHttpApplication(Application.java:586)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpSite$HttpApplicationRunTimeReference.createHttpApplicationFromReference(HttpSite.java:1987)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpSite$HttpApplicationRunTimeReference.createHttpApplicationFromReference(HttpSite.java:1970)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpSite$HttpApplicationRunTimeReference.getHttpApplication(HttpSite.java:1922)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpSite.getApplication(HttpSite.java:423)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.resolveApplication(HttpRequestHandler.java:398)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:439)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.serveOneRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:221)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:122)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:111)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.procClientSocket(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:234)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.access$700(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:29)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler$AcceptHandlerHorse.run(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:879)
    at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:298)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: oracle.classloader.util.AnnotatedClassFormatError: Bad version number in .class file

      Ugyldig klasse: dk.myproject.bII.login.actions.LoginActionForm
             Indlæser: current-workspace-app.web.DefaultProject:0.0.0
        Kodekilde: /C:/workspace/myproject/test/Return/libs/BUtilities.jar
      Konfiguration: <classpath> in C:\workspace\myproject\test\Return\Client\public_html

    Afhængig klasse: org.apache.struts.config.FormBeanConfig
             Indlæser: current-workspace-app.web.DefaultProject:0.0.0
        Kodekilde: /C:/jdevstudio10134/jakarta-struts/lib/struts.jar
      Konfiguration: <classpath> in C:\workspace\myproject\test\Return\Client\public_html

    at oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.defineClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:2285)
    at oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.findLocalClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:1462)
    at oracle.classloader.SearchPolicy$FindLocal.getClass(SearchPolicy.java:167)
    at oracle.classloader.SearchSequence.getClass(SearchSequence.java:119)
    at oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.internalLoadClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:1674)
    at oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.loadClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:1635)
    at oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.loadClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:1620)
    at org.apache.struts.config.FormBeanConfig.formBeanClass(FormBeanConfig.java:320)
    at org.apache.struts.config.FormBeanConfig.setType(FormBeanConfig.java:191)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.defineClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:2241)
    ... 52 more
2014-05-21 07:39:32,019 [HTTPThreadGroup-4] ERROR org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet - Parsing error processing resource path 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2540)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2566)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseElement(NonValidatingParser.java:1288)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.ValidatingParser.parseRootElement(ValidatingParser.java:146)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:303)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:206)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1548)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile(ActionServlet.java:1006)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:955)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:470)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:256)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.loadServlet(HttpApplication.java:2379)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.findServlet(HttpApplication.java:4830)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.findServlet(HttpApplication.java:4754)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.initPreloadServlets(HttpApplication.java:4942)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.initDynamic(HttpApplication.java:1144)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.<init>(HttpApplication.java:741)
    at com.evermind.server.ApplicationStateRunning.getHttpApplication(ApplicationStateRunning.java:431)
    at com.evermind.server.Application.getHttpApplication(Application.java:586)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpSite$HttpApplicationRunTimeReference.createHttpApplicationFromReference(HttpSite.java:1987)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpSite$HttpApplicationRunTimeReference.createHttpApplicationFromReference(HttpSite.java:1970)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpSite$HttpApplicationRunTimeReference.getHttpApplication(HttpSite.java:1922)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpSite.getApplication(HttpSite.java:423)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.resolveApplication(HttpRequestHandler.java:398)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:439)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.serveOneRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:221)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:122)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:111)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.procClientSocket(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:234)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.access$700(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:29)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler$AcceptHandlerHorse.run(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:879)
    at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:298)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
2014-05-21 07:39:32,034 [HTTPThreadGroup-4] ERROR _jsp._generalError - javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot retrieve mapping for action /AjaxActions
```

Translation of some of stack trace:

```
 Ugyldig klasse: dk.myproject.bII.login.actions.LoginActionForm
             Indlæser: current-workspace-app.web.DefaultProject:0.0.0
        Kodekilde: /C:/workspace/myproject/test/Return/libs/BUtilities.jar
      Konfiguration: <classpath> in C:\workspace\myproject\test\Return\Client\public_html
```

Translates into:

```
Invalid class : ....
loading: ....
sourcecode : ...
configuration : ....
```

Update :
Have check all jar files, all are version 49 (java 1.5) maximum.
Anyone knows how to check the version that the embedded oc4j can run ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does the Danish explanation come from?

Comment: No idea tbh. must be the java\oc4j that takes my system.locale into account. But I'll just submit a loose translation of it

Comment: You might have a dependency compiled for Java 6 (if oc4j supports Java 5) which is pulled in when the digester wants to set a property (probably when reading an XML file).  You can use "javap" to sample some classes in all your various jar files to see the version number.  If I recall correctly it is shown with "-s".  You can also download a Java 5 from Oracle and use the "-verbose" flag to see which class have been read in just before the exception happens.

Answer (score 1):

Generally that error occurs when you have your project on higher version of JAVA as compare to the oc4j. You have to check the JRE version of oc4j and you have build your project with that version.

I am not sure about Netbeans but If you are using eclipse then you have to make two changes in your project: -
1. Goto project properties and select Java Compiler, change the version as per the version on oc4j

2. Goto project properties and select project facets  and change the version of JAVA here as well

Hope this helps